# Javascript quality profile use is flipping after each new analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I noticed that after each sonar analyse, the use of the 'Sonar way' (Javascript) profile is switching. 
Then each time it's re-enabled we have all JavaScript issues tagged as new!

What can be the cause of this behavior ?
How can I fix it ?

Thanks for any advice.

[image: Sonar activity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three possibilities:

- you have someone with too much time on his/her hands manually flipping the configuration
- you have `sonar.profile` somewhere in your analysis configuration. The question is how/why it would be getting set/unset
- you have a person or more likely process that is resetting what the default JavaScript profile is.

I'm guessing there was some attempt to automate/ensure the use of the Sonar way profile that has somehow gone awry.

I would closely check your job configuration to see if `sonar.profile` appears anywhere in it and to see if there are any web services calls that might be (re)setting what the default is.

Comment: I didn't find the exact cause, but after I updated sonar and our build server to their latest version, the problem doesn't occur anymore. I hope it will stay that way.